# ListView findViewById returning null

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm not using a ListActivity because I want to extend FragmentActivity. Instead I'm trying to use:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
```

Unfortunately lv is null.

In my xml I have:

```
 <ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

I've also tried using different android id's for the list view such as the one you have to use when you use ListActivity, but it's always Null.

Edit: I was trying to call findViewById before calling setContentView. Calling setContentView first fixed it.

Comment: Can you show as your entire layout?

Comment: are you calling it before you call `setContentView()`?

Comment: please provide complete activity code

Comment: @Andy If you call after `setContentView()`,try clean/Build and restart eclipse.

Comment: Hi JRaymond, I was trying to use findViewById before calling setContentView.  If you want to add an answer I'll accept it.  Next time I will provide more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JRaymond mentioned in a comment awhile ago, I needed to call setContentView before using findViewById.

Answer (score 2):

You should put `setContentView` on top of `findViewById`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
```

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

remove it from your Listview in xml and use like

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```